# ¿Cómo convertir los elementos de un array en objetos a partir de sus valores?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Teniendo este array json

```
$scope.ports= ["0001|XXX", "0002|YYY", "0003|ZZZ"];
```

busco la forma de poder llamarlo así :

```
[
{code:"0001",
name:"XXX"
},
{
code: "0002:,
name: "YYY"
},
{
code:"0003",
name: "ZZZ"
}
];
```

Para poder mostrar solamente el nombre del código y no el código en si, pero no se puede ya que en el arreglo original toma a "0001|XXX" un valor como tal.
Va por el lado de usar un split() y separarlo según el caracter "|".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Puedes utilizar la función `map` del array para recorrer cada uno de los elementos del array y convertirlos en objetos. Estos objetos serán almacenados en un nuevo array.

Utilizaremos la función `split("|")` para separar los valores de cada uno de los elementos del array tomando como referencia el símbolo `|`.

Ejemplo:

```js
var array = ["0001|XXX", "0002|YYY", "0003|ZZZ"];

var resultado = array.map(function(elemento){
  var dividir = elemento.split("|");
  return {code: dividir[0], name: dividir[1]};
});

console.log(resultado);
```

Comment: Usando ES6: `const [ code, name ] = element.split('|'); return { code, name }`.

Answer (score 0):

```
var ports =  ["0001|XXX", "0002|YYY", "0003|ZZZ"];
var ports2 = [];
var largo = a.length;

for (var i = 0; i < largo; i++) {
  // Divide el elemento del arreglo en dos partes segun la posicion de |
  var dividido = a[i].split('|');

  // Inicializa un diccionario, asigna el primero elemento del arreglo dividido a 
  // la clave code y el segundo a la clave name.
  var obj = {
    code : dividido[0],
    name : dividido[1]
  }

  // Añade el diccionario al final del segundo arreglo
  ports2.push(obj);
}

// El codigo del primer elemento es..
var codigo = ports2[0]['code'];

// El nombre del primer elemento es..
var nombre = ports[0]['name'];
```